# For Loop in Worksheet change malfunction

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, worksheet

Please I have an issue, everytime a change occcurs on the sheet it affects all the rows instead of the row (i) concerned. Confused. Don't for-loops work for worksheet_change ? Pls help. Thanks.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim LR As Long

'create a variable for last row of column C, LR
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row


For i = 2 To LR
      If Cells(i, 6) = "Yes" And Cells(i, 7).Value = "Full" Then 
       Target.Value = Cells(i, 3).Value
       Cells(i, 9).ClearContents
       Cells(i, 10).Value = Cells(i, 8).Value + Cells(i, 9).Value
     End If
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G" & i & ":G" & LR)) Is Nothing And Range("F" & i) = "Yes" 
    And Target.Value = "Full" Then
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Cells(i, 8).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value
      Cells(i, 9).ClearContents
      Cells(i, 10).Value = Cells(i, 8).Value + Cells(i, 9).Value
      Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G" & i & ":G" & LR)) Is Nothing And Range("F" & i) = "Yes" And 
    Target.Value = "Portion" Then
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Cells(i, 8).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value
      Cells(i, 10).Value = Cells(i, 8).Value + Cells(i, 9).Value
      Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You're looping through all the rows, so naturally it will affect all the rows. Also, you need to disable events in your first `If` block.

Comment: Furthermore I would suggest, that you use correct indenting for the `for`-loop and `If`- statements - then it is much easier to read what is going on.

Comment: You launch your event when a cell is changed, and inside that event, you change cells. Aren't you creating some infinite loop of events, calling themselves, like this?

Comment: @Rory the codes work but issue I'm having is that once I change the row from "Full" to "Portion" it affects all the cells and not just the one I change. Tried a couple of things to change this but to no avail. Thanks

Comment: @Dominique pls how do you recommend I go about it? when I change a cell from "Full" to "Portion" it affects all the previous cells and not just the one I change

Comment: @greg616: see my answer.

Comment: @Dominique Seen it, thanks. The said columns (A-E) already have values. It's a really robust sheet with lots of info. If 6th and 7th column values are "Yes" and "Full" respectively, I  want to automate 8th, 9th and 10th. Also if 6th and 7th column values are "Yes" and "Portion". But when I change one cell to "Portion" previous automated "full" rows are affected.

Comment: @greg616: glad to see my answer is useful. You can modify the `IF`-clause in my answer, checking on column number, value, ....

Comment: @Dominique still have the same issue of changing one row and other previous rows affected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to launch this event for the columns A-E. So, you can start your macro with:

```
IF Target.Column <= 5 THEN
...
END IF 'at the end of your macro
```

Like this, when you launch code like `Cells(i, 8).Value = ...`, `Cells(i, 10).Value = ...`, ... this macro will be called but it will be stopped immediately.

Apparently you are checking on column, maximum 10, which is in the range of the cells you are changing within your macro. Let's go for another approach:

At the very beginning of your macro, put this line:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

At the very end of your macro, put this line:

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

(and remove the other occurences).

This will make sure you don't call your macro while running it.

Comment: Used ``` If Target.Column <= 10 And Range("F" & i) = "Yes" And Target.Value = "Full" Then ```. Still having the same issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dominique. Refactored the code a bit with your insights and it's working well now